# To search almost any file based on context on Windows

Tags: windows, search

I would like to get a software recommendation for searching files on Windows with advanced search features. Since the Search bar of Windows 10 is pretty slow and is not able to identify files faster, I am in need of a software which can search for files based on property, its usage history in minimum search time.

Comment: Are you searching only for file names, or for content? If content, which kinds of files do you want to search? Text only? PDF? MS office? Linbre Office? Search in archives?  The more detail you give us, the more likely we are to be able to help you.

Comment: I won't post this as an answer, since your question is so unclear (please  read [ask]).  Your answer *migh* be [Agent ransack](https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack)

Comment: [This](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/26817/program-to-search-by-file-name-in-windows/26822#26822) answer your question.

Comment: "search for files based on property, its usage history" - what does this mean?

Answer (score 2):

For searching filename in Windows, **Everything** is the best option for you : https://www.voidtools.com/

For searching file content inside, I recommend **TextSeek**, a fast and easy desktop search tool. And you can find files without indexing :  https://www.textseek.net/

Answer (score 1):

Look at Copernic Desktop Search (link below). I used it during the XP age of windows and loved it. A must have utility of that time.

There is also Everything from voidtools. It is portable and I use it nowadays.

1. Copernic **Desktop Search**: http://www.copernic.com/en/products/desktop-search/
2. voidtools **Everything**: https://www.voidtools.com/

There are many other options out there, however I find these 2 the best. Hope this helps. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Windows doesn't have a complete index of the locations you are searching within. Check out your indexing options first, Windows 7 and newer actually do quite a decent job on searching for stuff without 3rd party software.

Also, store the stuff you need to quickly access on SSD, if you have one. To improve your search results appearing with the Start Menu, you might want to substitute it with [Classic Shell](http://www.classicshell.net/).